# Reading from Text File in _layouts folder C#

Tags: filenotfoundexception, 2007

I'm running into a problem while trying to read from a text file I have stored in my _layouts/myaspapp folder.  I've tried everything I've been able to find on the web, but will always either get a File Not Found error (while trying to use StreamReader or something similar or a 401 Unauthorized (using HttpWebRequest/Response).

I'm out of ideas on how to access this file and read the text from it.  I am able to see the text file itself if I go to http://server/_layouts/myaspapp/text.txt, but I have not been able to open it and read it from C#.

Any tips or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: A quick question: why read it through the IIS and not directly from the file system?

Comment: Disregard from my comment if you are reading it from outside of Sharepoint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
string contents = string.Empty;    
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
response.Close();
```