# How to read a file from a folder in _Layouts?

Tags: visual-studio, layouts, mapped-folder

I have a file that is in a the mapped folder "Layouts" in my Visual Studio project.  I would like to read the contents of this file but I have been having some trouble accessing it.  What I have tried:

```
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(web.Url + "/_layouts/MyPoject/data.xml");
        reader.Read();
```

But when i get to the `reader.Read();` link it throws a 404 error.  Is there a different way that I should be accessing this file?

Comment: basic question: are you sure your url is correct ? (MyPoject instead of MyProject)

Comment: try to get the file with the url in browser and see if path is correct

Comment: Check this as well : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/251fc7c9-ac02-482c-b22b-39e045f6475c/

Comment: @ZiadWAKIM good catch.  Unfortunately the project name is right.  I changed it before I posted it here and must have mistyped.

Answer (score 12):

Since your file in _layouts directory, why not to use [GetGenericSetupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getgenericsetuppath.aspx) method?
Something like this:

```
var path = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyPoject\data.xml");
```

**UPD:**

This method is obsolete in SharePoint 2013, you should use [GetCurrentGenericSetupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getcurrentgenericsetuppath.aspx) or [GetVersionedGenericSetupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getversionedgenericsetuppath.aspx)

Thanks for noticing that fact in comments.

Comment: Doesn't that just get me a path?  I need to actually read the file.

Comment: try this code:  `var path = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyPoject\data.xml"); XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);reader.Read();
` using this method you open file by its physical path, not by uri. but it depends on your needs.

Comment: I know this is old but people will find it on Google. This is now obsolete in SP2013. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getgenericsetuppath.aspx

Comment: Can confirm. Did find on Google. Update very useful. Thankyou x

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to pass your default credentials for this to work.

Check [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/reading-from-text-file-in-layouts-folder-c) where a text file is read from a layouts folder. I believe you are having similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are putting the file in layouts, can I assume this is a file that going to remain static, and not be edited?

If that is the case you might like to try an alternative method, and that is to take advantage of the .NET resource framework.

Rather than put the xml file in the layouts folder, create a resources file in your VS project (eg Strings.resx)

Open the file and from the designer, select files from the top-left dropdown.

Drag and drop your xml file onto the designer. You now have the ability to access the content of the file as a string by simply using object.property form, for example

string xmlcontent = Strings.XmlFile1;

Once you have the xml in a string variable, you can do what you like with it eg load into and XmlDocument object.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it via webrequest:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

XmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
reader.Read();
```

Remember disposing ;)

Comment: Hi @pyranha, Its the same solution that is provided in the link above.

Comment: oops didnt see that. copied it from one of my projects. if this didn't help check the url. probably use a absolute url for testing.

Comment: What would I dispose?

Comment: Dispose the XmlTextReader Object and the WebResponse Object.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(xslFileUrl);           
return File.ReadAllText(path);
```