# SPWeb.getFile(Url) exception : value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I suffer from a problem of

> value does not fall within the expected range

from below code.

```
         string webUrl = "/_layouts/15/wfcourrierdep/ArticlesList.aspx";
                string fullpath = SPUtility.GetFullUrl(SPContext.Current.Site,   
                webUrl);

        SPFile file = web.GetFile(fullpath);
```

What can the cause be?

Answer (score 2):

It could be a problem of `SPUtility.GetFullUrl` not being able to work with layouts URLs (since they are shared between all sites in your farm, and not site specific)

Try if

```
string fullPath=SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, webUrl)
```

works better.

Don't really now why you are trying to get a file from the virtual directory layouts though! Check for example here of how to read from this directory: [How to read a file from a folder in _Layouts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23798/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-folder-in-layouts)

If possible, you should consider to deploy the file into a library in SharePoint instead. That way you could do CRUD on it just like any other file in SharePoint

Comment: there's no method CombineUrl

Comment: Sorry ConcatUrls! But I think you will still have problems working with layouts files

Comment: unfortunately still the same error

Comment: As I said, I think the problem is that you can not use GetFile for files in the layouts folder! Check the link in my post for how to work with those files like you would in regular asp.net

Comment: to clarify more please

Comment: Mhm, depends on the typ of file you want to read (I still do not understand why you should read a file from the layouts folder, it is not standard procedure and not a best practice). All examples I have seen reads XML (which your aspx really is in essence): `var path = SPUtility.GetCurrentGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyPoject\data.xml"); XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);reader.Read();`

Comment: unfortunately again gave the physical path but generate the same error

Comment: If you get that from submitting a path like the one in my latest comment it would indicate that you: either provide an incorrect path, or that the file does not exist

Comment: i verify either are correct: i verify first the file it does exist after delpying my solution and the full path is : http://servername:port/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/wfcourrierdep/ArticlesList.aspx

Comment: Well you should not use the full path with this code.. You should use @"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\wfcourrierdep\ArticlesList.aspx". But I will say this once more: If you need this type of interaction with a file, don't deploy it to the layouts folder, deploy it to a document library of some kind in a site

Comment: this is what i did : string path = SPUtility.GetCurrentGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\wfcourrierdep\ArticlesList.aspx"); gave me the physical path of the file

Comment: We appear get the error when we have an Event Receiver that fires for a FQDN (http://portal.domain.com), but then does a GetFile on just the short-name (http://portal).

Comment: your code sinppet works fine for me Make sure the app page has been deployed properly to the folder. Verify that your file really does exist in the path.
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\wfcourrierdep"